# How to for loop span tags in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I condense this many span tags? I am trying to get it as small as possible. Any advice helps, thanks!

```
<header>
<a href="#" class="loo">cat <i class="fa-d fa-ct"></i></a>>
<div class="particle">
  <span style="--i:50;"></span>
  <span style="--i:21;"></span>
  <span style="--i:16;"></span>
  <span style="--i:18;"></span>
  <span style="--i:13;"></span>
  <span style="--i:22;"></span>
  <span style="--i:15;"></span>
  <span style="--i:24;"></span>
  <span style="--i:17;"></span>
  <span style="--i:28;"></span>
  <span style="--i:12;"></span>
  <span style="--i:26;"></span>
  <span style="--i:23;"></span>
  <span style="--i:13;"></span>
  <span style="--i:17;"></span>
  <span style="--i:11;"></span>
  <span style="--i:21;"></span>
  <span style="--i:16;"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

This is why I am trying to get. Each --i:Number creates a particle at random times.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by condence?

Comment: can't you just have 1 span element and clone it?

Comment: How are the spans currently generated?

Answer (score 1):

In case you were looking for a more compact way of generating the HTML, then maybe the following is helpful?

```js
const html=[...new Array(18)].map(_=>`<span style="--i:${Math.ceil(Math.random()*40+10)};"></span>`).join("\n");
console.log(html); // can be commented out ...
document.querySelector(".particle").innerHTML=html;
```

```html
<header>
 <a href="#" class="loo">cat <i class="fa-d fa-ct"></i></a>
 <div class="particle"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: You are the GOAT!!